# Some SSRS reports are showing a status of PENDING

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a library of over live 100 SSRS reports. Most are scheduled and the schedules run either daily, weekly or monthly. Last Friday 11 showed a status of PENDING. The status of these reports is still PENDING 5 days on. There is nothing that links only these 11 reports. The schedule they use is daily which is used by over 60 other reports. The data source is the live system which is the same data source as 99% of the reports. 
I am guessing that something happened on Friday that caused these reports to error. All reports work fine manually. How can I force them to run correctly as a schedule again?

EG:
[image]

Comment: Has someone important left recently? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2008/07/10/tip-change-the-owner-of-sql-reporting-services-subscription/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No-one has left recently. I was able to resolve this issue by accessing the subscription on each report and selecting FINISH without making changes. The subscriptions worked fine after that. 
Still none the wiser on why it happened.